# Can domain extensions which do not currently offer domain privacy offer it later?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar

I'm not sure if there are any examples of this happening (if at all), but given how many domain extensions that are available today, can any domain extension that do not offer domain privacy offer it in the future?

Comment: This question makes your last one clearer that you'd like to register a domain with an extension for which there are no registrars offering a privacy service. There's nothing in ICANN's base RAA preventing them from adding that service on, although [ICANN plans to develop an accreditation program](https://whois.icann.org/en/privacy-and-proxy-services) for it. There might be governmental restrictions however that preclude using privacy (usually in countries with a history of misuse, like with `.tk` domains). What is the domain extension?

Comment: @dan There are several I came across (out of curiosity). Few of them: `.im , .in , .yt , .club, .organic` . [Even though there are thousands of extensions out there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains), I bet that a lot won't see much use...but ones gaining in popularity like `.ai ` still do not (two letter ones seem like the biggest culprits due to them being tied to countries).

Comment: It might depend on the registrar (each approved registry can have several accredited registrars). For example, [.club](https://www.godaddy.com/help/about-club-domain-names-9121) and [.yt](https://www.gandi.net/domain/yt/info) can be purchased with privacy (click on those links to verify). [Here's](https://www.dynadot.com/community/help/question/domain-privacy-not-allowed) a list of some that might not (yet). If they've been released relatively recently, agreements might have been created between proxy/privacy services (usually the registrar itself) and the registry. In some cases...

Comment: they might not be implemented yet or are in the process. In other cases, governmental restrictions might prevent or curtail them (due to negotiations/money between the registrar -> registry -> governing body). So it's pretty difficult to say if they'll offer privacy services in the future or not...but the age of the application with ICANN, and stability/business practices of the local governments are probably clues (sometimes covered in their Wikipedia entry, like this one for [.tk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.tk#Abuse), pointing to why it doesn't offer privacy).

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, for a given TLD you have its (sole) registry and then many registrars (there are exceptions of course). Then you have separately "proxy services". When you, through a registrar, register a domain name at the registry, if you carefully read the registry-registrant contract you will see that you are forced to give true information and any error may lead to the domain being taken back from you or deleted.

Now, 2 things happen :

1. because of various EU rules, EU based registries are mandated to take extra care of personal information (for physical persons); in many cases they make sure it is not publicly seen, for example in `whois` output. This is the case for example for `.EU` or `.FR`. The registry still has your full data, but just protect it
2. various registrars and third parties proxy services provide you with a service where they put their own data as owner of the domain name but make sure all contacts, for example through email, are redirected to you, since you have a contract with them. It is only in this way that your information is undisclosed to the registry but it has drawbacks also: in case of problems, you are not, for the registry, the true owner of the domain. So for really high value domain names people/companies choose to do the same thing but use their attorney or something like that as proxy.

On top of that, for gTLDs, you have an ICANN program that registrars are mandated to follow where they at least annually contact their client and make sure the information is correct, and ask them to correct it if not. Failure to do that may lead to the domain name being deleted.

As for ccTLDs, the legal rules they have to follow may change and they may need to adapt. So privacy handling may change in the future. But I think you will have more chance having providers (registrars or third parties) starting or stopping to provide services like that than having registry change their rules.

For gTLDs registries (under contract with ICANN) it would be very hard for them to provide services like that, they would need a lot of arguing, and it is only when local laws are contradictory that they would more easily be able to do that (see `.TEL` and `.CAT` cases in the past).

Answer (score 0):

Given that many of the new domains are handled by new and private registries, the best answer is "possibly".

More than likely they *can* offer domain privacy, whether or not they *will* is another matter entirely.